# How do installation discs keep track of install counts?

Tags: installation, anti-piracy

Many install discs only let you install the software X number of times.

However discs are stateless. They are unchanged (AFAIK) after installation. So This puzzles me.

How do they keep track?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They get in touch with the company servers in the background to validate the install (not all apps but most network connected apps).

Comment: This was my first thought, but I thought they didn't need to be connected to the internet. Otherwise couldn't someone just shut off the internet connection before installing? .. Well come to think of it, I think this when it lets you install but says you need an internet connection to validate install. Still, I could have sworn I installed something before that kept track without being networked. Maybe I was mistaken.

Comment: Well, it really depends on the product you are trying to install. Some let you install and then convert you to a trial mode unless you validate your install by going online. For an offline app that doesn't require any kind of online interaction, it is technically impossible for the author to limit your install. These days, most apps need to go online to update or do other stuff and that is when they get you!

Comment: Ahh gotcha. `"that is when they get you!"` just FYI, I was just curious, I am not trying to bypass anything. :)

Comment: There are various open source alternatives for most tasks and I used to debate with myself whenever I install anything on my client's machines that required a key/serial. I personally use a Mac and buy apps for smaller $ amounts and there are so many free ones!

Answer (score 0):

In many ways. If you're on Microsoft windows, most likely the installation program writes the number of used installations in a key of the windows registry.

You can use ProcMon to monitor the keys accessed by a process during execution, it's a free tool from Microsoft.

Comment: I am more talking about when you install on separate computers.

Comment: In that case the only possible way is that the program does an online check.